# How fast is simplexml_load_file()?

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml, last.fm

I'm fetching lots of user data via last.fm's API for my mashup. I do this every week as I have to collect listening data.

I fetch the data through their REST API and XML: more specifically `simplexml_load_file()`.

The script is taking ridiculously long. For about 2 300 users, the script takes 30min to fetch only the names of artists. I have to fix it now, otherwise my hosting company will shut me down. I've siphoned out all other options, it is the XML that is slowing the script.

I now have to figure out whether last.fm has a slow API (or is limiting calls without them telling us), or whether PHP's simplexml is actually rather slow.

One thing I realised is that the XML request fetches a lot more than I need, but I can't limit it through the API (ie give me info on only 3 bands, not 70). But "big" XML files only get to about 20kb. Could it be that, that is slowing down the script? Having to load 20kb into an object for each of the 2300 users?

Doesn't make sense that it can be that... I just need confirmation that it is probably last.fm's slow API. Or is it?

Any other help you can provide?

Comment: Czn you post some code? Are you doing 2300 api calls?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing 2 300 api calls.

Comment: are your calls similar to this?
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=library.getartists&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&user=joanofarctan

Answer (score 1):

I don't think simple xml is that slow, it's slow because it is a parser but I think the 2300 curl/file_get_contents are taking a lot more time. Also why don't fetch the data and just use simplexml_load_string, do you really need to put those file on the disk of the server ?

At least loading from memory should speed up a bit things, also what kind of processing are you going on the loaded xmls ? are you sure you processing is efficient as it could be ?

Comment: It isn't the processing, I've tested that. It is the act of using "simplexml_load_file"... So you are saying I should get the xml from last.fm and then load it locally?

Comment: Loading from memory would at least spare few io

Answer (score 1):

20kb * 2300 users is ~45MB. If you're downloading at ~25kB/sec, it will take 30 minutes just to download the data, let alone parse it.

Comment: Whoa, it could be this... but the data is download from server to server. It can't be THAT slow.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the XML that you download from last.fm is gzipped. You'd probably have to include the correct HTTP header to tell the server you support gzip. It would speed up the download but eat more server resources with the ungzipping part.

Also consider using asynchronous downloads to free server resources. It won't necessarily speed the process up, but it should make the server administrators happy.

If the XML itself is big, use a SAX parser, instead of a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a limit of 1 API call per second. I'm not sure this policy is being enforced through code, but it might have something to do with it. You can ask the Last.fm staff on IRC at [irc.last.fm](http://irc://irc.last.fm) #audioscrobbler if you believe this to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, fetch the data and parse using `simplexml_load_string` rather than relying on `simplexml_load_file` - it works out about twice as fast. Here's some code:

```
function simplexml_load_file2($url, $timeout = 30) {


// parse domain etc from url
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
if(!$url_parts || !array_key_exists('host', $url_parts)) return false;

$fp = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], 80, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
if($fp) 
{
    $path = array_key_exists('path', $url_parts) ? $url_parts['path'] : '/'; 
    if(array_key_exists('query', $url_parts)) 
    {
        $path .= '?' . $url_parts['query'];
    }

    // make request
    $out = "GET $path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: " . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $out);

    // get response
    $resp = "";
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $resp .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $parts = explode("\r\n\r\n", $resp);
    $headers = array_shift($parts);

    $status_regex = "/HTTP\/1\.\d\s(\d+)/";
    if(preg_match($status_regex, $headers, $matches) && $matches[1] == 200)
    {
        $xml = join("\r\n\r\n", $parts);    
        return @simplexml_load_string($xml);            
    }   

}
return false; }
```